# Trying to understand interaction of interrupts, noInterrupts and delays

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm having trouble understanding how to activate interrupts so that they operate only when they should. With this code, I seem to get erratic performance when I either attach or unattached interrupts, or when I try using noInterrupts.
What I am trying to accomplish is to deactivate the alarm function from running until a slight delay is initiated upon hitting an incorrect key. That would allow leaving the premises without triggering the interrupt. Does noInterrupt only affect the function in which it is placed??

```
///////////////////////// initialize & includes //////////////////////////
#include "SIM900.h"
#include "sms.h"
#include "Keypad.h"
#include <GSM.h>
SMSGSM sms;
//To change pins for Software Serial, use the two lines in GSM.cpp.
int PIR_SensorPin = 2;
int LED_OutPin = 11; //green
int Alarm_OutPin = 12; //red
int alarm_count = 0;
volatile boolean trigsensor = false;
boolean away = false;
const byte interruptPin = 2;
int z = 0;
int i = 0;
int timeout = 10000;

//////////////////////////// setup keyPad //////////////////////////
const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //four columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] =
{
  {
    '1', '2', '3', 'A'
  }
  ,
  {
    '4', '5', '6', 'B'
  }
  ,
  {
    '7', '8', '9', 'C'
  }
  ,
  {
    '*', '0', '#', 'D'
  }
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {
  6, 7, A2, A3 // row pin# on keypad to Arduino pin#, ie Row Pin #1 goes to Arduino Pin #6, etc.
}; // connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {
  3, A0, A1, A4
}; // connect to the column pinouts of the keypad
Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );
const char PIN[5] = {
  '9', '6', '7', '9', '#'
}; // PIN number
char key_input[5] = {
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0
}; // used for comparison

//////////////////////////////// setup ///////////////////////////////////
void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);  // Establish Serial connection;
  pinMode (LED_OutPin, OUTPUT);   // Set pinMode.
  pinMode (Alarm_OutPin, OUTPUT);   // Set pinMode.
  pinMode (PIR_SensorPin, INPUT);   // Set pinMode.
  digitalWrite (LED_OutPin, LOW); // Set output pins to LOW for start.
  digitalWrite (Alarm_OutPin, LOW); // Set output pins to LOW for start.
  digitalWrite (PIR_SensorPin, LOW);
  Serial.println ("Studio Alarm starting up."); // Serial message that GSM shield is starting up
  if (gsm.begin(4800)) {    // Set GSM shield to recommended 4800 baud rate.
    Serial.println ("Status = Network READY");
    digitalWrite (LED_OutPin, HIGH);
  }
  attachInterrupt (digitalPinToInterrupt (2), trigger, HIGH); // PIR as interrupt
  Serial.println ("System Ready");
}

//////////////////////////////// void loop ///////////////////////////////////
void loop()
{
  readKeypad(); // Serial.println ("at keypad");
  if (trigsensor == true) {
    alarm ();
  }
}

///////////////////////////// void trigger ///////////////////////////////////
void trigger() {
  trigsensor = true;
  alarm();
}

//////////////////////////////// void alarm ///////////////////////////////////
void alarm() {
  Serial.print ("away="); Serial.print (away); Serial.print (" "); Serial.print ("trigsensor="); Serial.println (trigsensor);
  Serial.println ("at Alarm");
  if (away == true && trigsensor == true) {
    noInterrupts();////////////////////////////////
    // (sms.SendSMS("**********", "***Motion Detected in Studio!***"));
    Serial.println ("MOTION detected: SMS Sent");
    for (alarm_count = 0; alarm_count <= 5; alarm_count++) { // Cycle outputs if triggered
      digitalWrite (Alarm_OutPin, HIGH); delay (1000); // On/Off/On/Off/Off
      digitalWrite (Alarm_OutPin, LOW); delay (500);
      digitalWrite (LED_OutPin, HIGH); // delay (1000);
      //   digitalWrite (LED_OutPin, LOW); delay (1000);// End by turning off light
      Serial.println (alarm_count);
    }
  }
  trigsensor = false;
  readKeypad();
}

//////////////////////////////// read Keypad ///////////////////////////////////
void readKeypad() {
  char key = keypad.getKey();
  if (key != NO_KEY) { // if a keypad input
    key_input[z] = key;
    tone(10, 900, 100);
    Serial.print ("Key_input["); Serial.print(z); Serial.print ("] = "); Serial.println(key);
    z++;
    if (z >= sizeof(key_input)) {
      z = 0;
    }
    switch (key) {
      case '*': // resets key_inputs to "0"
        z = 0;
        break;
      case '#': // pressed to "enter"
        z = 0;
        for ( i = 0;   i < 4 ;  i++ ) {
          Serial.print(key_input[i]);
        }
        Serial.println ("-------");
        delay(100); // for extra de-bounce
        checkPIN();
        break;
    }
  }
}

//////////////////////////////// check PIN ///////////////////////////////////
void checkPIN() {
  Serial.println ("@ checkPIN ");
  int correct = 0;
  int i;
  for ( i = 0;   i < (sizeof(PIN) - 1) ;  i++ ) {
    if (key_input[i] == PIN[i]) {
      correct++;
    }
  }
  if (correct >= sizeof(PIN) - 1) {
    Serial.print ("# correct = "); Serial.println (correct); Serial.println (sizeof(PIN) - 1);
    correctPIN();
  }
  else {
    incorrectPIN();
  }
}

//////////////////////////////// correct PIN ///////////////////////////////////
void correctPIN() {              // do this if correct PIN entered
  Serial.println ("@ correct PIN ");
  digitalWrite (LED_OutPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite (LED_OutPin, LOW);
  trigsensor = false;
  away = false;
  readKeypad();
}

///////////////////////////// incorrect PIN ///////////////////////////////////
void incorrectPIN() {           // do this if incorrect PIN entered
  noInterrupts();
  Serial.println ("@ incorrect PIN ");
  //detachInterrupt(0); Serial.println ("interrupt off 1");
  trigsensor = false;
  away = true;
  digitalWrite (LED_OutPin, HIGH);
  delay(timeout);
  attachInterrupt (digitalPinToInterrupt (2), trigger, HIGH); Serial.println ("interrupt on 2");
  alarm(); Serial.println ("here");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, I think attaching and detaching interrupts isn't really something that you should do to often. It also won't really make your code very much more readable.

You may have a look at programming (embedded systems) in general. A technique I like to do is making a (non-blocking) state machine. In this way you don't even need interrupts (you can actually have interrupts if you want, though).

Also, it may be worth noting that making your code more readable and understandable is likely going to improve your "idea of what is going on" and thus improve it's reliability. This is commonly done by designing and applying "scope" to your code. You've done well on the keypad functions, giving them a sane name and reasoning. You could've put them in a class, but that's not where the errors are at.

Basically, your alarm has a few states:

- Armed
- Unarmed
- Alarm!
- Just activated

From these, you can form a state diagram.
Usually, "events" lead to the state of your system being changed.
For example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fovRMM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Sorry for "abusing" the schematic editor (:  )
As you can see, events can be user interaction/sensors/timing, basically anything.

By designing your code in a state diagram, you get an idea of what you want your machine to do, at what moment. And what other states it can go to from there (and when/how).

Your code will become something along the lines of:

setup

```
enum STATE{
  armed,
  unarmed,
  justActivated,
  alarm
};

STATE systemState = unarmed;
long timeGettingArmed;
```

loop

```
switch(systemState){
   case armed:
   if(breakinSensor.check() == HIGH){
      systemState = alarm;
   }else if(keyPad.check() == deactivated){
      systemState = unarmed;
   }
   break;
   case unarmed:
   if(armButton.check() == HIGH){
      timeGettingArmed = millis(); // Or you could just do a delay here.
      systemState = justActivated;
   }
   break;
   case justActivated:
   if(timeGettingArmed + waitTime < millis()){
     systemState = armed;
   }
   break;
   case alarm:
   if(keyPad.check() == deactivated){
     systemState = unarmed;
   }else{
     beep();
   }
   break;
}
```

Ofcourse you'll have to highly adapt this code to suit your needs, I doubt it will even compile. But it can also be a part of designing your program, try just writing it out in words (or explaining it to someone), before you program it.

*You could make use of the interrupts by checking in the interrupt if the state is "armed" and then setting the state to "alarm". This way you avoid the interrupt messing up any of your logic and having to disable it.

The cool thing of this "non-blocking" (if you don't use delays) state machine is that you can actually add more statemachines to it, and it will seem like the processor does everything at the same time. This is because it skips rather fast through the "i/o checks".

Comment: Your approach seems valid, but my issues to date are always getting sidetracked with trying to implement new techniques that I don't fully understand. The result is that I have been working on this project way too long. I will attempt your ideas on my next project.